# XML schemas for modelling finite algebraic structures and substructures

Tags: xml, xsd, algebraic-data-types

1. Are there any ready-to-use XML schemas for modelling finite algebraic structures such as finite rings, finite groups, finite fields etc.?  Or I should I think about OpenMath?  There is no clear and user friendly resource which I've found that describes how to model a finite group structure, say, as an XML schema.
2. In general, which of the following types of databases are faster, in principle, for applications such as publishing to the web: relational databases, native XML databases, object-oriented databases?  In particular, does anyone familiar with the BaseX XML native database system know how it compares with relational databases?

The context of this question is that I've got a large and increasingly unmanageable dataset of some 48000 "records" containing information about certain set substructures inside finite groups.  Actually, these substructures are triples (S,T,U) of nonempty subsets S,T,U of a group G, say, with the defining property which is called TPP.  I will also mention that this dataset was compiled from the output of a search program written in the Groups, Algorithms and Programming (GAP) computer algebra system.  Now, each record is essentially an information record about the TPP triple, stating (1) the name of the group, and some key attributes of the group, like say, whether it is simple, or abelian etc., (2) the names or GAP identifiers for the elements composing each member of the triple, (3) and some numerical information about the triple like its 'size', 'cardinality pattern' etc.  I want to write an XML schema which captures the structure of this TPP triple record, so that I can store each TPP triple record as an XML document constrained by the schema, and enter the records into an XML database like BaseX.

Obviously I've thought about a relational database for this purpose.  But I wondered whether it could be faster to use a native XML database like BaseX.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to your first question the answer is no, because there are only academical works in this field and it's hard to access them. One time I had such a problem and it was difficult for me to find something worth. But as you know XML Schema is context free grammar so a language specified by a grammar can be accepted by a finite state automaton and therefore it's not hard to implement some algebraic structure via XML Schema. When I did some research in Semantic Web I also was interested in this theme and can say there are not many material on it. You can read this article for the most common information http://csconf.org/Volume2/page405.pdf

OpenMath is a bad language for this purpose and you better do it by yourself.
And with regard to a second question there are a lot of material accross the Internet. But the most common - you can't compare such databases they are completely different. But I can recommend you to integrate XML DB with relational DB (there exist common ways of mapping- you can look at such experimental projects as X-Ray